# Unfiltered square-wave as feedback in class D amplifier

Tags: feedback, class-d

I found this little circuit that (ab)uses a [TL494 SMPS PWM controller](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf) as PWM driver for a class D audio amplifier:
[image]

([Source article @ Geekcircuits.com )](http://geekcircuits.com/2010/07/class-d-amp-using-tl494-dc-to-dc-converter-chip-2/)

It uses the unfiltered, but constant amplitude (due to D1/D2), output square wave as negative feedback for the error amplifier inside the  TL494. How does this work? How can a square wave be used as negative feedback to be added to a music signal ?

The source article does not really explain this in any detail.

Comment: I don't know exactly but consider: 1)Output feedback is averaged on C7, then TL497-pin2 sees fractions of this average, output square wave and input signal as R5/R18 divider back and forth rules. 2)TL497 error amplifier is used without any compensation nor gain setting (pin3 is open) so do not regard it as a linear circuit but like a comparator

Comment: Is this a pure curiosity/theory question or one aimed at a practical application?  Class-D amplifier technology has come a long way; sophisticated packaged parts designed to address the fundamental challenges with minimal external components are inexpensive and widely available.   It's possible that when that was written sometime around 2005 options were limited enough that cleverly re-purposing a chip from 1983 made sense - but today?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Just a theoretical question, can't figure out how that feedback setup is supposed to work.